# JavaScript: Sum values of object array grouped by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects and need to group the objects by property `type` and sum their respective values.

My array looks like this:

```
var array = [
{ type: 'A', value: 100 },
{ type: 'B', value: 50 },
{ type: 'A', value: 200 },
{ type: 'A', value: 50 },
{ type: 'B', value: 70 },
{ type: 'C', value: 10 } ]
```

Desired result:

```
var result = [
{ type: 'A', value: 350 },
{ type: 'B', value: 120 },
{ type: 'C', value: 10 } ]
```

Sorting is not necessary but I need to find a way to group the objects by `type` value and then add up their `value`.

Does anybody know how to solve this? I tried some filtering but didn't end up with the desired result.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  This question asks how to group AND sum values.  The other question was on how to group by topic and subtopics.  The answer to this question doesn't answer the other question. If I were to post the answer to this question there I would be chided for being off-topic there.

Comment: const result = groupTotals(array);    console.log(result);    function groupTotals(array) { const result = {};    for (let index in array ) { const a = array[index];    ( !result[a.type] ) ? result[a.type] = a.value : result[a.type] = a.value += result[a.type] ; }    return result;  }